# how to upload video file WYSIWYG editor in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, upload, video

I can't upload a video file through WYSIWYG editor. Sometimes it says `File validation failed.`. Sometimes it simply doesn't do anything while uploading a file.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Hi What video file?  mp4? avi?

Comment: both video file

Comment: on witch one you had error? because avi is supported , mp4 no and you need add functionality for second one

Comment: Can you try to upload  first avi file from this site http://www.engr.colostate.edu/me/facil/dynamics/avis.htm and tell me is it working. In magento upload choice html5

Answer (score 1):

You can add mp4 for example that way:

Copy `vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml`
to `yourvendor/YourTheme/Magento_Cms/etc/di.xml`

and add this to `media_allowed`

```
            <item name="mp4" xsi:type="number">1</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to upload product video then there is one more method do it via YouTube. These are the steps which you have to follow:

- Upload your video to YouTube.
- Go to google developer console and generate YouTube Data API.
- Then add the generated Youtube API key to your Magento 2 store by
  going to STORES --> Configuration.
- At last, just add Video URL (YouTube) to your product edit page.